# How to integrate VLC framework build to my project

Tags: ios, swift, libvlc

I want to use VLCKit into my project, i followed this tutorial :

- Clone http://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit.git
- open your favorite terminal application such as Terminal.app or iTerm 2 and navigate to your checkout.
- execute ./buildMobileVLCKit.sh
- check -h for available options such as -s to compile for the simulator
- build as a static framework with device and simulator support: ./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -f

After those steps i got those files in the image bellow :

[image]

How i can use those files into my project ?? Thank's in advance

Comment: Im doing the same steps above. But not getting the static library. Could you please help me?

Comment: where are you getting these frameworks? in the bundle itself?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cocoapods` to easily integrate `MobileVLCKit` in your app.
Just add `pod "MobileVLCKit"` in you `podfile` and you are good to go.

Comment: used and see it very slow/lost buffer when play rtsp/rtmp video. Do you have anymore solution?

Comment: I hear people use FFMPEG player for RTSP. May be it's worth a look. https://github.com/imoreapps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos. Let me know if it solves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static framework, drop it to your Xcodeproj, setup the correct system frameworks you need to link and you should be good to go!